# Leave App sometimes appearing instead of Disallow App

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have a similar query to [Can someone please put an end to "LEAVE APP" misery!](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5085566/can-someone-please-put-an-end-to-leave-app-misery) with a differing behaviour.

Our application asks for permissions, the user gets an allow / disallow option, however if the user clicks to try to authorise again (within a short space of time) they will instead see a dialog with allow / leave app.

This is disrupting our application flow slightly as the leave application will take users directly to their facebook profile and not back to our site (as we explain the benefits of allowing our application).

Has anyone experienced this and / or knows a way to prevent this from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost sure this is deliberate, and designed to provide a way for users to quickly exit authentication loops

Comment: I figured it might be as much it just isn't documented anywhere but then this is the Facebook API.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intentional design choice in the permissions dialog. It can't be overridden.